# Quais as vantagens de usar o controle formView do ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, formview

Quais as vantagens de usar o controle `formView` do ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este tipo de controle ASP.NET lhe oferece uma certa "agilidade" para construção de formulários de edição, criação e visualização de dados. Pode parecer vantajoso se formos levar em conta todo seu suporte para um CRUD básico (create, read, update, delete) porem a sua customização vai demandar domínio sobre o componente, onde uma simples troca de DataSource vai requere um pequeno estudo (tente utiliza-lo com MySql e vera) e no final de contas você verá que este esforço não valeu apena.

Recomendaria você a criar seus próprios html e adequar a sua necessidade, porem veja este artigo do DevMedia que aborda a criação de uma tela para cadastro de clientes:
http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-ao-controle-formview-do-asp-net/27554

Comment: formview é aquele tipo de controle que a gente sabe que existe, mas nunca vai precisar usar.

Comment: Cleiton, de certa forma sim, porem quem já trabalhou com ASP.NET Dynamic Data Web Application (http://www.devmedia.com.br/integracao-dynamic-data-web-application-parte-1/22020) sabe que este tipo projeto usa fortemente o FormView, onde criar um simples template customizado pode se tornar um pesadelo.